# reading parameters from registers instead of from stack

Tags: linux-kernel, parameter-passing

Last week the instructor told about handling interrupts in linux and especially do_IRQ function. I wondered why does do_IRQ function read its parameter from register instead of from stack. But the instructor also did not know the reason of this. Now I am still wondering  why some kernel functions like do_IRQ read the required parameters from registers instead of from stack. I googled it but i only found functions read their parameters from registers or stack but not the reason.

Comment: Have a google for "calling conventions"

Comment: Could it be there is confusion here between the calling convention and the availability of the register stack frame to the IRQ functions?

Answer (score 0):

Since kernel 2.6, all kernel functions use registers, rather than the stack, to pass the first 3 parameters (6 in x86_64).
In the ancient 2.4 kernel, only a few performance-critical functions, such as `do_IRQ`, work this way. Does your instructor teach you about the 2.4 kernel?!

Passing parameters in registers improves performance.
It's much faster to read/write registers, compared to memory (even if it's in the L1 cache).

In all cases, it's very important that the caller and callee would agree about the parameter passing method.
When a function uses a non-standard method, it's marked with a compiler attribute.
This attribute tells the compiler two things - when compiling the function itself, it knows where parameters are to be expected, and when compiling calls to it, it knows where to put them.